# Post Based Slider

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have implemented Post based Slider Type in Revolution Slider.Post based Slider will fetch post data and show feature image as a slider images.But my question is when no post is found then i want to show any default images in slider.So, how it could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You must try to use "Default featured image" plugin in WordPress and set your default feature image.

Use this link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: Thanks for contributing time and giving answer Dhaval. But as per your given link of plugin it will set default feature image for post(when feature image is not set) and i want to set default image for revolution slider.That default image will be shown when no post is created or all the post are deleted.